# Android Studio can't find activity

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am working with Android Studio 1.0 when suddenly, out of the blue I can not run my app on my phone because it is telling me that it can not find the default activity.

Changing the "default activity" to the specific activity I want to launch, ends in the error that apparently the activity I selected is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml.
Which also isn't true, because I did declare it in the .xml, I didn't remove it or add something new, it always has been there and now it doesn't want to work.

Thank you for reading and maybe answering / commenting. :D

Edit: This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pack.aproject" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondPageActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you added the intent-filter with MAIN action and LAUNCHER category to your main activity?

Comment: @bigdestroyer Yes, I did that.

Comment: can you please share your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: What is this with not posting codes thing? How can we help you if you dont provide us with your code? Obviously it's something wrong inside your code...not with your phone or Android Studio

Comment: @Android007 There you go, I included it.

Comment: Actually Android Studio has been buggy, so there is a very good chance it is IDE related.

Comment: @zgc7009 Ye, possibly, just getting on my nerves, it worked perfectly but now it doesn't.

Comment: can you post the mainactivity.java

Comment: Try doing a 'rebuild project' so it performs a clean rebuild. Unfortunately, sometimes studio will get a little confused with XML changes (but not nearly as bad as eclipse.)

Answer (score 3):

you may need to refresh the IDE's cache.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```